# How to update code on multiple EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-ec2, synchronization, elastic-load-balancer

I created an Elastic Load Balancer in front of two EC2 instances. However, I discovered an issue that requires me to update the code on both EC2 instances.

I can access each instance individually to update code via github, or I could create an AMI to launch a new instance. It's very unfavorable.

How can I synchronize code between the two EC2 instances?

Answer (score 0):

In situations like this either a code pipeline would be helpful OR better yet switch to Elastic Beanstalk.